# Include special characters from Chinese sentences

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, formatting

I don't want to remove special characters from the given string. Please tell me how can I modify my regex variable so that it will not remove the special characters from my chinese sentences.

For example,

**这项治疗费用很高。**

I do not want to remove this **"。"** character from the sentence> How can I make this work?

Sorry asking such question because I'm new to programming.

```
  def spliteKeyWord(str):
        regex = r"[\u4e00-\ufaff]|[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+\'*[a-z]*"
        matches = re.findall(regex, str, re.UNICODE)
        return matches
```

Comment: Which characters do you wish to remove? A character class might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"。" character has "\u3002" Unicode hexadecimal character code. Just add it to your regex:

```
regex = r"[\u4e00-\ufaff,\u3002]|[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+\'*[a-z]*"
```

Comment: but its just working for full stop. can you please give me generic solution for all special characters.??

Comment: I don't know anything about chinese special characters, but you can convert UTF-8 symbols of your special chars to Unicode for example here: http://ratfactor.com/utf-8-to-unicode